# What is the difference between 'a' and "a"?

Tags: c++, string, char

I am learning C++ and have got a question that I cannot find the answer to.

What is the difference between a `char` constant (using single quotes) and a string constant (with double quotes)?

All my search results related to char arrays vs `std::string`. I am after the difference between `'a'` and `"a"`.

Would there be a difference in doing the following:

```
cout << "a";
cout << 'a';
```

Comment: Try putting in more than one character and observing the differences.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`'a'` is a character literal. It's of type `char`, with the value 97 on most systems (the ASCII/Latin-1/Unicode encoding for the letter `a`).

`"a"` is a string literal.  It's of type `const char[2]`, and refers to an array of 2 `char`s with values `'a'` and `'\0'`. In most, but not all, contexts, a reference to `"a"` will be implicitly converted to a pointer to the first character of the string.

Both

```
cout << 'a';
```

and

```
cout << "a";
```

happen to produce the same output, but for different reasons. The first prints a single character value. The second successively prints all the characters of the string (except for the terminating `'\0'`) -- which happens to be the single character `'a'`.

String literals can be arbitrarily long, such as `"abcdefg"`. Character literals almost always contain just a single character. (You can have *multicharacter literals*, such as `'ab'`, but their values are implementation-defined and they're very rarely useful.)

(In C, which you didn't ask about, `'a'` is of type `int`, and `"a"` is of type `char[2]` (no `const`)).

Comment: Thanks, is the string literal the same as the type included with #include <string>?

Comment: @james, No, the latter is a class that encapsulates the former, making it much easier to use.

Comment: @james: No, a string literal is of type `const char[]`, but `<string>` defines a type `std::string`. C++ inherited string literals from C; `std::string` is specific to C++.

Comment: @chris: Except that a `std::string` isn't terminated by a `'\0'` null character.

Comment: I do think it's worth noting that this is an area where C differs from C++ in a way many people don't expect. As you (entirely correctly) said, in C++ a character literal like `'a'` has type `char` -- but in C, it has type `int`.

Answer (score 4):

`"a"` is an array of characters that just happens to only contain one character, or two if you count the `\0` at the end. `'a'` is one character. They're not the same thing. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(char c) {
    printf("Got character %c\n", c);
}

void test(const char* c) {
    printf("Got string %s\n", c);
}

int main() {
    test('c');
    test("c");
}
```

This will use two different overloads; see http://codepad.org/okl0UcCN for a demo.

Comment: printf/stdio.h are best avoided as tools for illuminating C++ questions...! :-/

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are used to surround character literals.  Double quotes are used to surround string (character array) literals.

Many interfaces, such as `cout <<`, accept either.

Answer (score 0):

A single quoted `'a'` is a literal of type `char`. A double quoted `"a"` is a null-terminated string literal of `char`s.

Answer (score 0):

- "a" -> it denotes it is a string. in c++ string is a collection of
  characters array.
- so string is terminated by **delimiter '\0'** it indicates the end of string.
- so its size would be 2 because 1-byte for "a" and 1-byte for '\0'

where in case of 'a'-> it is single character. so its size would be 1-byte.

```
char str[]="a";
```

or

```
char *ptr = "c";

for  'c' -> char c = 'a';
```

or we can write as well

```
char c = 97;
```

Answer (score -1):

'a' - 1) Character constant
        2) size - 1 Character
        3) Not a collection of Character   array

"a" -1)  String literals
        2)  size - 2 Character
        3) collection of Character array